# Visual Studio 2019 16.10.03 - Braces are all black

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide

Ive downloaded the new Version of Microsoft Visual Studio (16.10.03) like 10 minutes ago and now all my braces and punctuation marks are black. Since i use the IDE in dark mode theyre barely readable anymore.

Ive even changed every color under "Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Color->Text Editor" to something non- black and it didnt solve the problem. Is there any way to change the color back to normal?

Here is an image for clarity:

[image: msvc after the update]

Comment: I'll ask the obvious questions. Did you try restarting VS? Your computer? Repairing VS?

Comment: It works fine for me with the provided light, dark, and blue themes. Perhaps try setting one of those if you have customizations.

Comment: Ive reinstalled vs - seems to have been a bug.

Comment: @pitue Which OS (version) are you using? [This issue was fixed in v16.7](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/braces-and-brackets-are-displayed-in-black-after-v/702493), still feel free to go thru the thread.